# What is the probability of an uncorrected bit error occurring and not being caught?

Tags: nas, file-corruption, memory-error

So I copied a setup exe from a nas drive to two seperate computers simultaneously today, and they both wound up having the same issues. The Setup exe has been used for time out of mind (at least, longer than I've been at this company) without issue, so that wasn't it, and the computers were literally brand new installs of windows.

After some fiddling with computer A I found that deleting the exe and recopying it and reinstalling the app resolved the issue, and the same thing for B.

The only conclusion I can come to is that some sort of Bit error occuring during the original disk read, both computers got the cached copy that was bad (identically) and both responded the same way.

It there is something else that could cause something like this, I'd love to know, otherwise what is the probability of this actually happening?

Comment: You will experience an uncaught/undetected bit error about once per 74TB of data that is read. For me, this equates to about twice a month on my home desktop. This is why servers use ECC registered memory (which is much better at detecting these issues) and why I use checksumming filesystems (like ZFS) for data storage.

Comment: Just curious, why 74 TB? In my computer networking classes there was all sorts of talk of parity bits and checksums and hashes and such to avoid errors, but the general tone of the lectures seemed to be that there were never any uncaught errors, or that they were so uncommon (and 1 bit out of 650910883643392 IS pretty uncommon) they were not worth mentioning.

Comment: @Sidney - Go ahead and convert that bit value to TB.  **Its around 75.776TB if you are wondering.**

Comment: @DarthAndroid, Why is this not an answer? It seems like you nailed the issue on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will experience an uncaught/undetected bit error about once per 74TB of data that is read. On my home desktop, this equates to about twice a month.

This is why servers use ECC memory (which is much better at detecting these issues and correcting them) and why I use checksumming filesystems (like ZFS) for data storage. If you're just storing data on partitions on your disk, then there's no way to verify that the data hasn't been modified. Even having a copy of the data (RAID 1), or parity data (RAID 5) isn't enough - It'll tell you that *something* changed, but it can't tell you what the original value was. Filesystems that support proper checksumming and redundancy can not only tell you which data has been corrupted/flipped, but can automatically recover it from the redundant copy.

A few years ago, 1 bit out of 650910883643392 *was* pretty uncommon. With cloud storage and the ever increasing quality of media (4K video is right around the corner), it has grown more and more common however.

Comment: ECC/non-ECC and registered/non-registered are not the same question. I think the only combination out of those that you don't see is registered non-ECC (generally, registered or buffered is only used with large memory module banks, but ECC can be done with single memory modules as well). My home system uses non-registered ECC RAM, for example.

Comment: I also feel that this answer would benefit from a source for the 1/(6.5e14) figure. It's worth noting that higher-grade HDDs report *uncorrectable read error* rates of *statistically* one sector error per around 1e15 bits read, which is in the neighborhood. Uncorrectable read errors are however by definition detected.